# Shopware 6 create DB entry for custom entity

Tags: plugins, shopware

I am trying to build a plugin for Shopware6 along the lines of BundleExample & Storefinder and am stuck on creating the corresponding entries for my entities. I added a module to the admin which has 3 components: list, detail and create
routed to [vendor-name].[plugin-name].list/.detail/.create respectively.

From custom\plugins[plugin-name]\src\Resources\administration\module[vendor-name]-[plugin-name]\index.js

```
    routes:{
        list:{
            component: '[vendor-name]-[plugin-name]-list',
            path: 'list'
        },
        detail:{
            component: '[vendor-name]-[plugin-name]-detail',
            path: 'detail/:id',
            meta:{
                parentPath: '[vendor-name].[plugin-name].list'
            }
        },
        create:{
            component: '[vendor-name]-[plugin-name]-create',
            path: 'create',
            meta:{
                parentPath: '[vendor-name].[plugin-name].list'
            }
        }
```

/list is displayed as expected when there are no entries in the DB, meaning only the smartbar is visible.
/detail cant work because there is no id since there are no entities yet. 
/create should generate an instance via

```
created(){
   this.repository = this.repositoryFactory.create('[vendor-name]_[plugin-name]');
   this.repository.create(this.context);
}
```

but nothing is happening.

I'm sure I'm overlooking a basic step somewhere and would appreciate any pointers as to how i can get it to actually generate an entry.
If further code would be helpfull to clarify the question I will gladly provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.repository.create(this.context);` line will create an entity object of your custom entity on the client side. 
To save that entity you have to call the `this.repository.save(entity, this.context);`.
Then you should be able to see an request being send to the server in the dev console of the browser.

For more information please take look in the [docs](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/internals/administration/cross-cutting-concerns/data-handling?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/internals/administration/cross-cutting-concerns#create-an-entity).

Keep in mind that `this.repository.create(this.context);` creates an empty dummy entity, so you at least need to set all the required fields of your custom entity.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I'm still getting my bearings and had not found that section of the docs.

I had assumed it would generate an empty shell with just an Id for me to fill in and save via the buttons once filled in the backend.